# Adding Tab space between String using Regular Expressions

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to add a Tab space in a string which looks like this:

```
String 1: 1.1_1ATitle of the Chapter
String 2: 1.1_1Title of the Chapter
```

There is no space between `"_1A" and "T"`.
or between `"_1" and "T"`.

The desired output is

```
1.1_1A      Title of the Chapter.
1.1_1       Title of the Chapter.
```

Here is what I tried:

```
string output=  Regex.Replace(input, "^([\\d.]+)", "$\t");
```

also

```
string output=  Regex.Replace(input, "^([\\d[A-Z]]+)", "$1 \t");
```

also

```
string output=  Regex.Replace(input, "^([\\d.]+)", "\\t");
```

Can I have a single Regex for both the inputs?

Many Thanks

Comment: @ClasG I have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've complicated thing quite a bit with the introduction of a letter in the version/index (or whatever the first part is). You might get it to work with this though:

```
([\d._]+(?:[A-Z](?=[A-Z]))?)
```

(Note! No C escaping of `\`. Check [ideone example](https://ideone.com/atijJO) for that.)

It grabs everything consisting of digits, dots and underscore. Then, in an **optional** non-capturing group, it matches (included in previous capture group) a capital letter, **if** it is followed by another capital letter (positive look-ahead).

This does however assume that the ***title* always starts with a capital letter**. I.e. if the *numeric* part is followed by **two** capital letters, it's assumed that the first is part of the *numeric* part.

Replace with `$1\t` to get desired effect.

[See it here at ideone](https://ideone.com/atijJO).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!!
Thank you so much!!
I hope the question gets rid of the negative vote!

Comment: Glad to help. Feel free to up-vote, if, as it says on the up-vote arrow, "This answer is useful" ;)

Comment: I did up-vote, since I have less than 15 reputation points, the post score is not  updated :(